# JSON - WepAPI - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, webservice-client

ANY help will be greatly appreciated

I have a Generic class that facilitates WebAPI calls, Its been in place for quite sometime and has had no issue. Today I'm getting an error and not sure where to track the problem. the exact error is

```
{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'PayLoad', line 1, position 12."}
```

what I'm getting back as the result of the call is

```
"{\"PayLoad\":[\"file_upload_null20180629155922²AAGUWVP2XUezeM3CiEnSOw.pdf\"],\"Success\":true,\"Message\":\"1 File(s) Uploaded\",\"Exceptions\":[]}"
```

Which looks right and is what I expect back from the service call

Here is the method that I'm calling that suddenly quit working, and its failing on the last line

```
        public static TR WebApiPost(string serveraddress, string endpoint, object data)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage msg;
        var clienthandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain)
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(clienthandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(serveraddress) })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            msg = client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        }

        var result = msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TR>(result);
    }
```

AND finally the line that actually makes the call (which should not matter)

```
returned = CallHelper<ResultStatus<string>>.WebApiPost(serviceurl, sendFileUrl, model);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where your web service is getting the value of PayLoad from, so it is very possible that the value has a Byte Order Mark (BOM) at its beginning.  This is especially the case if you are returning the content of what was originally a Unicode encoded file. 
Be aware that a BOM is NOT visible when you are viewing a string in the debugger.

On your web service, make sure that you are not returning a BOM in the value of PayLoad.  Check for this byte sequence at the beginning of the string:

```
0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
```

For more information on Byte Order Mark:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: All my calls return an object called a ResultStatus which has a few properties Success (bool did it work) a Message (string OK or summary of problem), Exceptions {list of strings containing detal of one or more issues) and an optional PayLoad of type TR in this case the Payload is a string

ResultStatus<string> means the payload is a string

Comment: Here is the result of the service call before the deserialization 

"{\"PayLoad\":[\"file_upload_null20180629155922²AAGUWVP2XUezeM3CiEnSOw.pdf\"],\"Success\":true,\"Message\":\"1 File(s) Uploaded\",\"Exceptions\":[]}"

Comment: I don't believe anything about the aspects of your setup mentioned in your comments are wrong -- what I'm referring to is a potential problem with the string in the PayLoad array, specifically file_upload_null20180629155922²AAGUWVP2XUezeM3CiEnSOw.pdf.  It looks innocent, but if the string contains a BOM (which you would not be able to see; you have to examine the bytes that make up the string) you can end up with parsing problems.  Try making your endpoint simply return "foobar" in the payload, if it works, you have a BOM problem...